# JWT - No authorization is added in the header in browser

Tags: java, angular, spring, security, jwt

I am using JWT and Spring security for developing a Forum Application. I am getting 403 error when accessing users' endpoints. It happened after the merge, previously everything working properly. The endpoint works properly from POSTMAN but the issue occurs when accessing from browser
Nothing in the code has been mixed up, now the Authorization header is not added to the request, but only in the endpoints for users, in other cases, it works. The bare token is stored at the local storage of the browser. What could be the reason for something like that?

**Angular interceptor adding authorization header**:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const authHeader = AUTHORIZATION_HEADER;
    const accessToken = this.authService.getAuthorization();
    if (accessToken !== null) {
      request = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set(authHeader, accessToken),
        withCredentials: false
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

**Angular Auth Service**

```
  login(userCredentials: UserCredentials): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post<AccountInfo>(`${API_URL}/login`, userCredentials, { observe: 'response' })
      .pipe(
        tap((response: HttpResponse<AccountInfo>) => {
          const token = response.headers.get(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
          this.storeAuthorization(token);

          const body = response.body;
          this.storeAccountInfo(body);
        })
      );
  }

  getAuthorization(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem(AUTHORIZATION_KEY);
  }

  private storeAuthorization(authToken: string) {
    localStorage.setItem(AUTHORIZATION_KEY, authToken);
  }

  private storeAccountInfo(accountInfo: AccountInfo) {
    localStorage.setItem(USERNAME_KEY, accountInfo.username);
    localStorage.setItem(ROLE_KEY, accountInfo.role.toString());
  }
```

Here is the git repo containing the source code
https://github.com/PatrykKleczkowski/Forum/tree/feature/improvments

Comment: Please provide only a code snippet were you think the problem is in order for others to help you, instead for them to navigate into the source of your repo

Comment: i really dont know where is the problem, because on my branch where i was working about admin-panel and everything was ok, now after merge is not working, so a more specific question is what could have influenced it